# only first paragraph appending javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to add multiple "p" elements with different inner texts but for some reason only one paragraph element in total is appending, which always seems to be the final one in the code.

My code is shown below. Thanks for the help.

HTML:

```
<select>
<option>Movie Title</option>
  <option>Movie Actor</option>
  <option>Genre</option>
  <option>Release Year</option>
</select>
  <input type="text" id="search">

<button id="submitSearch">SUBMIT</button>

<div id="searchresult">



</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var searchBtn = document.getElementById("submitSearch");
var userSearch = document.getElementById("search");
var resultDiv = document.getElementById("searchresult");

searchBtn.addEventListener("click",function(){
  var userMovie = userSearch.value.toLowerCase();
  //removing all white space from title
  var arraySearch = userMovie.split(" ");
  var convertedSearch = arraySearch.join("");
  if (!movies[convertedSearch]){
    console.log("Sorry, this does not match any DVD's you own");
  } else {
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    resultDiv.appendChild(para);
    para.innerText = "Title: " + movies[convertedSearch].title; 
    resultDiv.appendChild(para);
    para.innerText = "Cast: " + movies[convertedSearch].cast; 
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're not asking the browser to append two paragraphs: you're asking it to append the same one (`para`) twice. No DOM element can be in two places at once, so it is failing.

You need to repeat `para = document.createElement("p");` after appending it the first time. That will ask the browser to create two paragraphs and append them both.

Comment: Thanks for the response Andrew! I will vote for your answer as soon as enough time has passed and it allows me to. Many thanks for the help though.